# Get Column with formula's and get values only to new column

Tags: vba, excel

[image]My desired result is to have a separate column at column C, that has values only.

In Column "I" I have a range of data that is in in formulas.  I can copy and paste special to a new column to C and that gives me the values only.

But is there a better way to do this?  When I read data in New Column C, this gives the range of the pasted data which is messy meaning lots of white spaces.

Thanks :)

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(9).Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data? What do you mean by white spaces?

Comment: Sure no problem.  I mean like if I read this data externally or anything it gives white spaces.  But say if I wrote in an excel like 1, 2, 3 the true range would be found.  I used to have a fix but my hard drive got erased and I can't recall how I did it

Comment: @ProgSnob Sorry should have explained that better.  Poorly worded.  It gets the range of the cut and paste area and not the actual area of values

Comment: I do have a usb with some of backup files.  I'll cross my finger and pray for a miracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test.
S1: Select sheet contain data you want to copy
S2: run macro

```
   Sub macro1()
    Dim data As Variant
    data = ActiveSheet.Columns(9)

    ActiveSheet.Columns(3) = data
End Sub
```

if all of your data is number then just force is to convert to number

```
Sub macro1()
        Dim data As Variant
        data = ActiveSheet.Columns(9)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)

        If Len(data(i, 1)) > 0 Then
        data(i, 1) = CLng(data(i, 1))
        End If
        Next i


        ActiveSheet.Columns(3) = data
    End Sub
```

edited as you want to copy the whole column
p/s: this is not an optimize solutio as it read the whole column (1048576 rows)

Comment: Column C it still gives me blanks blanks under the last bit of data when reading.  I remember spending hours trying to figure this out last time.  Damn

Comment: try to change the color of your column font. may be it will reveal the mystery character.

Comment: You Legend!  Works like magic.  I had a close inspection of my job and turns out I had code in an incorrect order meaning it was working but not the way it should have.  Works 100%  Cheers

Comment: Now to make sure I save all this safe and sound and keep this job in working order :D

Comment: feeling greate to heard that it works. which one did you use? upper or lower ones?. both case pls check the source column and destination column ( here I choose 9 and 3 )

Comment: I've used both and they work perfectly.  I can definitely adjust as needed.  But this is awesome.  You saved me lots of searching countless articles and worry. Anyways I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in copying only values, you can do it like this:

Step 1: determine last row in column `I`: `lastRow = Cells(1, 9).End(xlDown).Row`.

Step 2: copy all values to column `C`:

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value
Next i
```

Putting it all together, the macro is:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim lastRow, i As Long
lastRow = Cells(1, 9).End(xlDown).Row
'alternatively specify explicitly amount of rows you want to copy, i.e.:
'lastRow = 25
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah for some reason when I read the data excel just knows that I used a botched method of cut and paste and it's like how dare you try and pass this off as data I know you used formulas mate..  There is another way to do this but I've looked through all my notes and it's vanished.  I can't believe I'm missing that bit of code.

Comment: Yeah sadly this does not resolve it.  Such a weird bug.  Not sure how to fix.  I imagine lots and lots of botched code testing until I find a new method to replace lost

Comment: Pretty standard formula.  =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$A$1:$B$400000,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP(A1,$A$1:$B$400000,2,0))

Comment: It works fine except for the fact that when I read it it doesn't seem to read the values (but like the previous formula length?).  It reads I dont even know what.  But I guess the real question I'll have to investigate is alternatives to copy and paste that don't screw with column length

Comment: Yeah same here tbh.  These methods should work in theory but excel be a heartless creature

Comment: Well, don't know how you tried my macro, but try it as a separate macro, just run as it is, don't append it to your code. Also, try changing `lastRow = Cells(1, 9).End(xlDown).Row` to `lastRow = 20` and see how that works. Also, could you delete previous comments, since they are not useful anymore :)

Comment: You are right.  It does work when I put row 20.  But it does not like detecting last row at all.  It's bizzare and I remember the solution last time was quite complex.  I am doubtful this issue will be solved easily

Comment: I can remedy this with trimming or by using a seperate excel.  Both are incredibly slow and the solution last time around did not require as such.  I however have no freaking clue how I did it so maybe I'll just trim it (hate doing it but you gotta do what you gotta do...

Comment: Hmm wait a second.  That nearly worked except for one blank.  What ius going on here.  I'm restarting pc.

Comment: You didn't tell that you have blanks in the column! So, set the `lastRow` to amount of rows you want to copy.